# concat unique child nodes in xslt

Tags: xslt

I need to concatenate nodes which are having distinct nodes in one parent node.

My XML is as mentioned below:

```
<AllEmails>
<MailObject>
<ToEmail>abc@gmail.com</ToEmail>
<CCEmail>def@gmail.com</CCEmail>
<Content>Content 1</Content>
</MailObject>
<MailObject>
<ToEmail>abc@gmail.com</ToEmail>
<CCEmail>def@gmail.com</CCEmail>
<Content>Content 2</Content>
</MailObject>
<MailObject>
<ToEmail>geh@gmail.com</ToEmail>
<CCEmail>ijk@gmail.com</CCEmail>
<Content>Content 3</Content>
</MailObject>
<MailObject>
<ToEmail>geh@gmail.com</ToEmail>
<CCEmail>ijk@gmail.com</CCEmail>
<Content>Content 4</Content>
</MailObject>
</AllEmails>
```

My XSL output should be like this:

```
<UniqueEmails>
<MailObject>
<ToEmail>abc@gmail.com</ToEmail>
<CCEmail>def@gmail.com</CCEmail>
<Content>Content 1, Content 2</Content>
</MailObject>
<MailObject>
<ToEmail>geh@gmail.com</ToEmail>
<CCEmail>ijk@gmail.com</CCEmail>
<Content>Content 3, Content 4</Content>
</MailObject>
</UniqueEmails>
```

Basically it needs to check for the unique "to" and "cc" email addresses and combine the content of those nodes and provide an output with concatenate of their contents. Expected result is to not to send same content repeatedly to same email addresses but to concatenate and send it as one email when the email addresses are same.

Comment: This is not a question and solution board here. There are other places in the internet to ask such question. If you have a problem with your XSLT you can ask here but in your samples is not even one line XSLT :(

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to use [Muenchian Grouping](http://www.jenitennison.com/xslt/grouping/muenchian.html). To match elements that have the same value for two different values, you can use a key that concatenates the values:
`<xsl:key name="mailkey" match="MailObject" use="concat(ToEmail,CCEmail)"/>`

Following XSLT

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
<xsl:output method="xml"  omit-xml-declaration="yes" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" />
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
<xsl:key name="mailkey" match="MailObject" use="concat(ToEmail,CCEmail)"/>
  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="AllEmails">
    <UniqueEmails>
      <xsl:for-each select="MailObject[count(. | key('mailkey',  
                            concat(ToEmail,CCEmail))[1]) = 1]">
      <xsl:variable name="current" select="concat(ToEmail,CCEmail)"/>
      <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()[not(name()='Content')]"/>
          <Content>
            <xsl:for-each select="//MailObject[concat(ToEmail,CCEmail)=$current]">
              <xsl:value-of select="Content"/>
                <xsl:if test="position() != last()">
                  <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
                </xsl:if>
            </xsl:for-each>
          </Content>
        </xsl:copy>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </UniqueEmails>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:transform>
```

when applied to your input XML generates the output

```
<UniqueEmails>
   <MailObject>
      <ToEmail>abc@gmail.com</ToEmail>
      <CCEmail>def@gmail.com</CCEmail>
      <Content>Content 1,Content 2</Content>
   </MailObject>
   <MailObject>
      <ToEmail>geh@gmail.com</ToEmail>
      <CCEmail>ijk@gmail.com</CCEmail>
      <Content>Content 3,Content 4</Content>
   </MailObject>
</UniqueEmails>
```

For detailed explanation of grouping using the Muenchian method, please check the article at the link provided above.
The `select="MailObject[count(. | key('mailkey', concat(ToEmail,CCEmail))[1]) = 1]"` at the `xsl:for-each` loop selects all unique `MailObect` elements withe the same value of the concatenation of the values `ToEmail` and `CCEmail`. In this loop all matching `MailObject` elements are copied, but the child node `Content` is omitted:

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()[not(name()='Content')]"/>
```

Instead, a new `Content` element is generated with the values of all `Content` children of `MailObject` elements that have the same value of `ToEmail` and `CCEmail` as the current `MailObject`:

```
<xsl:for-each select="//MailObject[concat(ToEmail,CCEmail)=$current]">
  <xsl:value-of select="Content"/>
```

and in case it's not the last element, `,` is added using [`position()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/XPath/Functions/position) and [`last()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/XPath/Functions/last):

```
<xsl:if test="position() != last()">
  <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
</xsl:if>
```